# Criar uma constante que carregue várias imagens e mostre-as na tela

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um game e ele está gerando apenas uma imagem na tela aleatoriamente. Eu gostaria de implementar 3 imagens diferentes, que através de um `random` fossem aparecendo automaticamente na tela, e que cada imagem tivesse um valor.

Exemplo:

```
imagem1 = 1;
imagem2 = 2;
```

Imagine o game fruit ninja!! O meu é parecido, só que no lugar das frutas o meu está apenas caindo 1 imagem de 1 quadrado.
Gostaria de adicionar mais imagens e não sei como criar.
Por exemplo, que fossem 3 quadrados; um amarelo, um verde e um azul, quero mostrar eles repetidamente na tela igual o fruit ninja.
Aleatoriamente ele chama uma imagem e apresenta na tela.
Meu código até agora, queria criar um método que fizesse isso mas não sei como!!

```
public class Inimigo extends Retangulo{ 
    private static Bitmap bmp; 
    public Inimigo(int x, int y, Resources res){
        super(x, y, 40, 40); 
        if(bmp==null){ 
            //instancio a imagem do resource 
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.amarelo); 
            //redimensiona a imagem 
            bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 40, 40, true); 
        }
    } 
    public void mexe(int height,int width){ 
        if (getY()<height){ 
            setY(getY()+5); 
        } 
        else{ 
            int x = (int)(Math.random()*(width-25));
            setX(x); setY(-25); 
        }
    } 
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){ 
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, getX(), getY(), paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi são 3 as suas dificuldades:

- Atribuir um valor a cada imagem
- Sortear uma de 3 imagens
- Apresentar uma imagem a cada 'x' segundos

Comece por declarar dois *arrays*, um com os *ids* dos *Drawables* que irá utilizar e outro com os valores atribuidos a eles.

```
int[] varImagens = {
    R.drawable.blue,
    R.drawable.grenn,
    R.drawable.yeollow
};

int[] varValores = {
    1,
    2,
    3
};
```

**Nota:** Caso os valores a atribuir sejam estes ou sequenciais o `array` não será necessário.
O valor pode ser calculado em função da posição(índice) que a imagem ocupa.

Para sortear uma imagem use:

```
int posicao = new Random().nextInt(varImagens.length);
int imagemId = varImagens[posicao];
int valor = varValores[posicao];
// ou
// int valor = posicao + 1;
```

Para que as imagens alternem a cada 'x' segundos use um *Timer*:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final boolean isRunnig = false;
-------------------

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        handle.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(isRunnig){
                    int posicao = new Random().nextInt(varImagens.length);
                    mostraImagem(posicao);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 3000); //Uma nova imagem é selecionada a cada 3 segundos
```

Dentro do método `run()` é utilizada a variável `isRunnig` para controlar a execução.
Terá de escrever o método `mostraImagem(int posicao)` que, de acordo com o valor passado, mostrará a imagem correspondente.
O método será chamado a cada 3 segundos se `isRunnig` for `true`

Isto é apenas uma base de partida.
Terá de ser você a fazer a implementação.

<sub><sub>**Nota:** Todo o código foi escrito diretamente na caixa de resposta. Desde já peço desculpas por algum erro de sintaxe.</sub></sub>

Comment: Huuuuuum entendi como fazer, muito obrigado!! OBRIGADO MESMOOOO, nem sei como te agradecer!! sucesso pra ti sempre, sim sim o método running ja esta pronto era só isso mesmo que eu não sabia como fazer.. Obrigado!! :D :D

Comment: No stackoverflow a melhor forma de [agradecer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a quem te ajudou é assinalar a melhor resposta e/ou votar naquelas que foram úteis.

Comment: O codigo acima nao funcionou! nao da erro mas nao funcionou, como eu faço para desenhar (posicao) no metodo draw que recebe bmp como imagem que esta dentro do metodo Imimigo

public Inimigo(int x, int y, Resources res) {
 super(x, y, 40, 40);
 if (bmp==null) {
 //instancio a imagem do resource
 //bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.amarelo);
       //redimensiona imagem
       bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 40, 40, true);
       }
}

private Bitmap bmp;
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
 canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, getX(), getY(), paint);
}

Comment: Não sei se entendi a sua questão. Mas para mover a imagem, tendo como base o código da pergunta, deve chamar o método `mexe` com as novas coordenadas e chamar o método  `postInvalidate()` da *view*, o que fará com que o rectângulo seja desenhado na nova posição.

Comment: isso ai mesmo, a logica é essa mesmo eu so nao estou conseguindo desenhalas na tela ao mesmo tempo... ou seja executar, quando executo a aplicação fecha..

Comment: Julgo que seria melhor criar nova pergunta, assim mais pessoas poderão vir a ajudar. Coloque nela a parte relevante do código e o log do erro.